# which modules should I use for real life object detection

Tags: python, camera, augmented-reality

I am trying to create a display that scans items on my camera and gives my information about that object.  I am not asking for any help with the code but which modules would be best for creating such a display.

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Requesting recommendations for off-site resources is off-topic.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First of all this is an odd question to put on StackOverflow since we revolve around helping each other with code. If you would like to create displays on a screen based on the targeted object you would want to use `import cv2` and `import tkinter`.  cv2 allows you to track objects on the camera and tkinter allows you to create displays.

Comment: Okay I will take that into consideration thank you

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions.

Comment: @Prune chill I was just trying to help the guy out he's clearly new